# VSCode Jupyter Extension: Rich syntax highlighting not working?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've just had to start from a fresh setup thanks to equipment failure, and this means configuring VSCode from scratch again. On my old set-up, Jupyter Notebooks (over SSH) would feature rich syntax highlighting identical to that used in raw .py files (photo 1):

[Raw .py syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Mmo.png)

However, in Jupyter notebooks, Pylance and intellisense work (I can mouseover and complete variables), but the rich syntax highlighting never does (photo 2):
[ipynb lack of syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmJwb.png)

This worked perfectly fine on my old system, and I was using the Dark+ theme as I am here. Any ideas as to what could be the cause of this? Many thanks all.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the Python and Jupyter extensions both locally and remote;
- Changing theme;
- Connecting to a different SSH host (the issue persists).

VSCode 1.60.0 (but the issue was also there in 1.59.x)

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Comment: @Arigion I submitted a [bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17472) and it's been triaged, but I've not heard anything back since.

Comment: Is there an update on this, did you ever solve the problem?

Comment: Just updating that I still get this issue. Neither of the answers solved the problem

Answer (score 54):

It can happen because there is conflict with Dependency Analytics extension with jupyter. Try to disable Dependency Analytics extension

Comment: I don't have that installed, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Disabling dependency analytics fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me after I disabled the extension and restarted the browser

Comment: This also fixed the issues I had with debugging Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code!

Comment: That's a kinda useful extension. Is there any other way to fix this? Yes, it does restore syntax highlighting in the notebooks but I don't want to give up Snyk vulnerability scanning everywhere else just to get colors back in the notebook.

Comment: Don't have that installed, what else can we try?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I solved it by switching from "Dark" theme to "Dark+".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My jupyter kernel was not selected, as soon as I selected one syntax highlighting started to work :)